VSCode Replace Regex with Regex
I created a script that create markdown files. The problem is that half of my <td> don't have an end statement and i have about 5000 to replace.
So I tried to use the Find and replace function of Vscode:
Statement to find all the <td> without any end:

<td>(?!.*<\/td>).*$

And now that the selection is good, how can I replace it to add the closing </td>
Theorically the solution should be something like this:

$1</td>

But I don't even know if it's possible to replaces with Regex statements. Or if there's another way to correct my mistake.
I already searched for my problem and found this

I think you mean $0</td> to get the whole match with $0 in the replacement. There is no group 1 in your regex.

Thanks a lot it worked, can you please write it as an answer and explain what are groups?
